# why in pyside2, cannot use QTranform mul QPointF?

Tags: python, python-3.7, pyside2

```
from PySide2.QtGui import QTransform
from PySide2.QtCore import QPointF
A = QTransform()
B = QPointF()
A*B
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation here, it looks like you can multiply them the other way around:
https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtransform.html#operator-2a-45